# Moving an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a problem when I tap on the "Cucina" button the white circle (top left of the photo) should move on the left of the button itself.
I'm using the following code:

```
 filter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
            layoutParams.setMargins(Math.round(filter2.getX()), Math.round(filter2.getY()), 0, 0);
            cerchioMenu.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        }
    });
```

but it does not work, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to re-drow your view again?

Comment: No, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onClick` event, you should get the button's coordinate like this:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
button.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

The `location` array will hold the button x and y coordinates. Now animate the white circle like this:

```
mCircle.animate().y(location[1]).setDurarion(200).start();
```

Remember to check for null and array index of `location` before doing any call on the array.

Comment: Glad I can help